# Save and Edit some Strings from loaded line to Text

Tags: c#, string

I have tried lots of codes posted here. And another places.

It doesn't do what want to do.

First See the code:

Load Button:

```
private void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextReader testTxt = new StreamReader(ItemBaseInfosPath);


        string read; 
        do  
        {
            read = testTxt.ReadLine();

            if (read.Contains(IDTxt.Text))
            {

                ConquerItemBaseInformation CIBI = new ConquerItemBaseInformation();
                CIBI.Parse(read);
                NameTxt.Text = CIBI.Name;
                LevelTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.Level);
                MaxAttackTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.MaxAttack);
                MinAttackTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.MinAttack);
                PhysicalTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.PhysicalDefence);
                DodgeTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.Dodge);
                MagicAttackTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.MagicAttack);
                MagicDefTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.MagicDefence);
                AttackRangeTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.AttackRange);
                PriceTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(CIBI.ConquerPointsWorth);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found.");
            }
        } while (read != null);
```

Save Button:

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextReader testTxt = new StreamReader(ItemBaseInfosPath);
        string read, read1, read2, read3, read4, read5, read6,
            read7, read8, read9, read10; 
        do  
        {

            read = testTxt.ReadLine();

            if (read.Contains(IDTxt.Text))
            {              


                ConquerItemBaseInformation CIBI = new ConquerItemBaseInformation();
                CIBI.Parse(read);
                CIBI.Name = NameTxt.Text;
                CIBI.Level = Convert.ToByte(LevelTxt.Text);
                CIBI.MaxAttack = Convert.ToByte(MaxAttackTxt.Text);
                MessageBox.Show(read);
                break;
            }

        } while (read != null);
    }
```

Load Button is working Great! Without problems. The problems in Save Button.

I got now the line, Example:`" 111003@@IronHelmet@@21@@0@@15@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@150@@0@@0@@0@@3@@0@@0@@0@@0@@3899@@3899@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@1@@1000@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@0@@Warrior'sHelmet@@None@@5@@0@@0@@0@@2020@@500@@"`

111003 is the ID, IronHelmet is the Name, 15 is the level.

It loaded. I want to save it. (Note for each of these have it's TextBox.

It's ItemEditor program, so I want when I edit anything in TextBox and Press "Save button"

It replace each of the edited things and save the text file again!:)

(Note: String.Replace("", ""); This code if I use it and the textbox that should edit, if it's value (Text) is 0 then it will change All Values of 0 in the Line! = Fail )

I hope you understand me!

Comment: If the delineatior is simply "@@", why not just concatenate all the strings together in the proper order?

Comment: @emd, I don't know what do you mean? :)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, but I can say that you must test `read != null` **before** calling `read.Contains`, not after.

Comment: @DourHighArch, Do you think that's the problem ( Or it will make any change? ). I know what you mean.. But What should have i to explain or do to make my request clear? :)

Comment: 1. Say what you want to do. 2. Say what the code does now. 3. Explain what is different between what you want and what it does.

Comment: @DourHighArch, Can you add me (MSN, Yahoo, Skype, Facebook)? I will show you my project (Team Viewer) and tell what i want to do and show you what it does. (Hotmail : GameHackerPM@hotmail.com , Yahoo : GameHackerPM@yahoo.com , SkyPe Username : gamehackerpm , Facebook : Facebook.com/GameHackerPM . Thanks.

Comment: I will help if you explain your problem here clearly. One of the goals of Stack Overflow is to provide searchable answers for others, and this will not happen if we post the answers vi IM. Explaining yourself clearly is also an important skill to learn. Try improving your question, or click Chat at the top of the page.